# Android: How to create a Facebook like images gallery grid?

Tags: android, gridview, image-gallery, staggered-gridview, staggeredgridlayout

I'm trying to implement a facebook like, gallery grid, where items have different sizes:

[image]

I was trying to use different libraries/solutions but for now without success:

1. I tried to use [AsymemetricGridView](https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView).
   But the problem with this implementation is that there are empty dead spaces left in the grid after going throw the adapter.
2. I also thought of using the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` and a `RecycleView`, but items, in this case, don't have equal or half sizes to other items as it implemented in the Facebook gallery.

Now I thinking of providing different view holders for different cases in the adapter, but I really don't like this idea. What is a better approach to this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have decided to use the [TwoWayView](http://lucasr.org/2014/07/31/the-new-twowayview/) library.

That you can get from: https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

In my code I did the following major changes:

Added TwoWayView in the xml layout:

```
 <org.lucasr.twowayview.widget.TwoWayView
            android:id="@+id/twvGrid"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            style="@style/TwoWayView"
            app:twowayview_layoutManager="SpannableGridLayoutManager"
            app:twowayview_numColumns="3"
            app:twowayview_numRows="3" />
```

In code I made the following changes:

```
private TwoWayView mTwvGrid;
.........

 mTwvGrid = (TwoWayView) findViewById(R.id.twvGrid);
    final Drawable divider = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider);
    mTwvGrid.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(divider));


    mTwvGrid.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            RequestManager glideRequestManager = Glide.with(TimelineStoryActivity.this);
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE || newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                glideRequestManager.resumeRequests();
            } else {
                glideRequestManager.pauseRequests();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {}
    });
.......

if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new TimelineStoryRecycleAdapter(this, mStory, mTwvGrid, this);
            mTwvGrid.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.setStory(mStory);
        }
```

Here is the end result:
[image]

Comment: @Emil Adz can u post code of your TimelineStoryRecycleAdapter, this view requires a ListAdapter , and in current android listadpter is an interface , so please help on how to desgin and apply the adapter

Comment: @Ak9637, Sorry, I can't as I don't have this class in my possession anymore.

Comment: ok, can u please explain this if possible   :   this view requires a ListAdapter , and in current android listadpter is an interface , so please help on how to desgin and apply the adapter

Comment: twoway-view is very much simpler and faster to implement than  AsymemetricGridView.

Comment: this library is not working now. any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use recyclerview with StaggeredGridLayoutManager to accomplish this. StaggeredGridLAyoutManager already handles this, also u can use setFullSpan for a image to use a whole row

Comment: If you look at section number 2 in my question, you will know that I tried this option but there is a problem with the heights of the items in the grid. I need to heights to be same of double the size.

Comment: whose height are u need , u can easily give a fix height to imageview to achieve this, i already saw your 2nd point