# How to implement Facebook photo grid alignment in Android

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager, staggeredgridlayout

In my app, I used [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) with spansize to align photos. However, this solution only creates static photo layout, not dynamic layout like Facebook's app.
For example, here are my grid layouts with 3 and 5 photos:
[image]

[image]

And here are Facebook's app grid layout with 3 and 5 photos:

[image]

[image]

I think that Facebook's app determines to use [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html) or [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) base on each photo's width and height to display the grid layout.
Anyone can give me a idea for implementing Facebook's grid photos?

Comment: Have you achieved this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check this [TwoWayView library](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) ?

It can help you to get desired output to some extend. According to library you can create following kind of things

[image]

add this to your gradle file

```
dependencies {
   compile 'org.lucasr.twowayview:twowayview:0.1.4'
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/tree/master/sample) is the sample of how to implement it. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36288167/3134215) thread as well.